# how to make JPanel's length and width extendible automatically?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

I have a JScrollPane and inside it I placed a JPanel.
There is also a button, when pressed, a rectangle of random length and width will be drawn
on the panel. So each time this button is pressed, the repaint method of the JPanel is called.

The problem is that sometimes the length of the rectangle is high and so the JPanel does not display it all, just part of it that already fits in the panel.

How can I make the JPanel display what is drawn inside it nomatter what the dimensions of the rectangle are?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  One solution might be to set the preferred size of the panel (to larger than the rectangle) and validate the scroll pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to draw the rectangle onto the `Graphics` object of a `BufferedImage` of similar dimensions, and then use this image as the `Icon` of a `JLabel`. Add this label to the panel at the arbitrary coordinates and then `revalidate` the `JScrollPane` and issue a `repaint` request.

Comment: if you are adding the JLabel everytime, then you dont' have to repaint or revalidate on JScrollPane, simply use setViewportView(Component view) or JViewport.setView(...), any method will do.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

your ScrollPane is limiting the size, default panel will stretch to accommodate it's child components. ScrollPane is fixed, that is why it is called ScrollPane, what you can do is programatically calculate the size of rectangle and repaint scrollpane with that size at each call of button press or better yet, you should know the possible sizes and make your GUI appropriate enough to make up for all such sizes.